# Two fully functioning profiles running simultaneously

Tags: linux, firefox, desktop-computer, gentoo, firefox-profile

**Question:**

Is it possible to open two different instances of Firefox, each running a separate profile, and have it so each time `firefox -P <profile name>` is run it will connect to the already running instance running that same profile (instead of creating yet another instance)?

My end goal is to have two different icons for Firefox (one for the first profile and one for the second) and have each profile behave like a completely separate program. In other words, when I click on either icon, I want it to behave as it normally would (using that profile, of course) and not even acknowledge the other instance/profile's existence. When I click on the other icon I want the same thing to happen: I want it to behave as though the other instance/profile doesn't exist.

**Research:**

I tried doing something fancy with a shell script to get this working. It checks for a running process with the specified profile. If it finds one, it will run `/usr/bin/firefox-bin -P $profile`. If it doesn't, it will create a new instance by running `/usr/bin/firefox -new-instance -P $profile`.

`$ cat /usr/local/bin/firefox`

```
#!/bin/bash

firefox=/usr/bin/firefox-bin

profile_running() {
    ps -Af | grep -v grep | grep firefox | grep -q -- "-P $1"
}

profile=$1
shift

if profile_running $profile; then
    $firefox $*
else
    $firefox -new-instance -P $profile $*
fi
```

---

In theory, if I ran this, I should have one instance of Firefox running using `-P first_profile` and one instance of Firefox running using `-P second_profile`. The former should have three windows open and the latter should have two windows open:

```
/usr/local/bin/firefox first_profile &
/usr/local/bin/firefox second_profile &
/usr/local/bin/firefox first_profile &
/usr/local/bin/firefox second_profile &
/usr/local/bin/firefox first_profile
```

However, what I found actually happens is not what I want. The good news is that each profile has exactly one instance running. However, the "first_profile" instance will have four windows open while the "second_profile" instance will have only one.

Any time I try to open a new "second_profile" window after the initial one, I get a new "first_profile" window instead. It seems that Firefox doesn't bother to check the `-P` parameter if it is attaching to an already-running instance.

**Conclusion:**

Since there seems to be no way to coerce Firefox into behaving the way I want it to using just command line arguments alone, I need to find a different course of action.

I am running **Firefox 33.0** (binary package) in **Gentoo Linux (amd64)**.

Answer (score 3):

This should answer your questions about running multiple profiles, I do it all the time. Even shows info on having one be a "default" profile so external links (like double-clicks or from other apps) will open in that default profile only.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_your_Mozilla_application_with_another_profile

It's short so I'll just paste it:

> When Firefox is running and you try to open another Firefox process, a
>   new window is opened instead, in the already running process. You can
>   use the -no-remote command line option to start a new Firefox process
>   that is invisible to the first process. [[1]](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=325509) By using -no-remote along
>   with the -P option to select a different profile, you can open
>   multiple instances of Firefox at the same time, using separate
>   profiles. [[2]](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=3173145#3173145) Selecting a different profile from the one used in the
>   first process is necessary because profiles are "locked" when in use.
>
> **Important**: Never use -no-remote to start the "default" profile (the
>   one that is set to open without asking when you launch Firefox).
>   That's because when you launch Firefox, for example, by clicking a
>   link in your mail program, you will get a Firefox is already running
>   but is not responding message if the default profile is already in
>   use. The solution is to always start the default profile normally and
>   launch all others with -no-remote. Then it will work. [[3]](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=3202348#3202348)
>
> You can use a shortcut to a specific profile to open Firefox using
>   -no-remote. For example, to open a profile named "My Profile" using -no-remote, enter the following in the Target field of a Windows desktop shortcut (adjust the path, if different):
>
> `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "My Profile" -no-remote`
>
> **Note**: You can also open the Profile Manager with Firefox already
>   running, by using -P -no-remote without including a profile name.